# navigate data between pages in jquery mobile without using external libraries

Tags: jquery-mobile

how to navigate the data between pages in query mobile without using external library. I have searched on google but i can't get the proper answer which is working correctly.

Comment: what kind of data you want to navigate, either we use webservices (dynamic data) or json files for static data,if you want to pass parameters then use window.sessionStorage to pass data between pages. Let us know the details please.

Comment: I want to send one value from one page to another page and I can fetch that value on second page without server connection(using javascript or Jquery or url passing)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so preferably do this:

In the page from which you want to pass set the sessionStorage item and in the other page get that item: (this works for persisting data untill the session is cleared)

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("param1","12345");
window.sessionStorage.getItem("param1");
```

Or simply use data-param="12345" in the element (div, listview etc..):

```
<div id="divId" data-param1=""></div>
$("#divId").data("param1", "12345");
```

and read it in other page:

```
$("#divId").data("param1");
```